# Preload next and previous pages and fade in on cursor keys

Tags: jquery, html

I am seeing many websites implementing seamless browsing between pages and I am wanting to implement this on a number of my sites. I am using WordPress, but that doesn't really affect this as such. I've never gone down the route of using Javascript to load new pages so this is new terratory for me. However I believe HTML5 does have page preloading capabilities.

I am looking for the first page to fade in from a blank screen and preload the previous and next pages. The next or previous page will fade (or slide) in seamlessly having previously been preloaded when the visitor...

- Clicks on the prev or next links
- Presses the left or right arrow keys
- if on a tablet, mobile or other touch device swipe left or right

The address bar should also show the next/previous page's url once loaded and browser history updated.

The best implementation of this that I have seen is The Next Web- http://thenextweb.com/

[On their announcement page](http://thenextweb.com/voice/2012/10/31/welcome-to-the-next-web-reader-edition/) they talked about this feature...

> Thanks to the brilliance of HTML5, readers can now browse the website
>   with fewer refreshes and near instant switching between articles. Try
>   it out, click the next button on this article or use…

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there a jQuery plugin or an easy way for me to achieve the above?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you research this yourself and tried anything?

Comment: @Jack - yes I've Googled and searched StackExchange etc and although there are a few examples that kind of do what I am looking for, they are very outdated and can't be relied upon. That's why I am posting here!

Comment: This is more of a venue to help you with specific code issues. Your question is a bit beyond that.